# Designing sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, fast-for-sharepoint

This is not a programming question, i am looking for some help for designing sharepoint 2010 site.

I have started learning sharepoint some time back by myself only.
I learned many of things like sharepoint programming, handlers and event, infopaths, webparts, BCS, powershell  and lot more.

Now i want to look towards the design part. Till now i always used the default sharepoint UI but now i want to design my site similar to the sites listed on this post.
 http://www.pinkpetrol.com/blog/2010/06/top-20-examples-of-creative-navigation-within-sharepoint/.
Also i find out there are sharepoint templates available on the internet, but i am not able to find out how to use them
I tried to find out some tutorials also but no luck.

Could some one please provide me some good tutorials for designing only.
It will be great help for me.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[Watch this Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msXn1en4WiU)
[Operating Systems and Server Administration](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/microsoft-sharepoint/9780470584644) -- Check this link